# How do I loop all buttons in my Form to change their text in C#

Tags: c#

I am new to C# and I use windows forms. I have `Form1` with 20 `buttons` on it (`button1` to `button20`).

How can I loop all those 20 `buttons` and change their text to for example "Hello" text?

Anyone knows how to achieve this? Thank you

Comment: Look at the related links on the right margin. ==>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Somewhere in your form's code behind:

```
foreach(var btnControl in this.Controls.OfType<Button>())
{
    btnControl.Text = "Hello";
}
```

Comment: ReSharper is a plugin for VS. Mine told me to get rid of "this" too. But I'm old school.

Comment: Wow, I mixed up your comment with "SharpDevelop". But yeah, it's just preference I guess.

Answer (score 1):

A simple loop will work find until you introduce containers into the page (groupboxes, tabs, etc). At that point you need a recursive function.

```
private void ChangeButtons(Control.ControlCollection controls)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < controls.Count; i++)
    {
        // The control is a container so we need to look at this control's
        // children to see if there are any buttons inside of it.
        if (controls[i].HasChildren)
        {
            ChangeButtons(controls[i].Controls);
        }

        // Make sure the control is a button and if so disable it.
        if (controls[i] is Button)
        {
            ((Button)controls[i]).Text = "Hello";
        }
    }
}
```

You then call this function passing in the Form's control collection.

```
ChangeButtons(this.Controls);
```